# Changing font color on mouseover and click javascript or html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a couple of html links, that I have onmouseover and onmouseout set to change colors, what I want to be able to do is when I click one of the links, the links is set to a certain color and mouse over effect no longer works on the clicked link but does on the others.  these links activate javascript functions but do not direct to another webpage.

Any ideas how I could do this?

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="paint" onclick="slidedown(this)"  style="color:#FFF" onmouseover="this.style.color = '#FF6600'" onmouseout="this.style.color = '#FFF'"><font style="font-family:pirulen; font-size:12px; margin-left:10px; "><b>Painting</b></font></a>
```

this is one of my links as you can see I have onmouseover and onmouseout set.

Comment: post your current code, so others can make sure any answers will suit your needs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this CSS to get the hover effect

```
a{
    color:#fff;
}
a:hover{
    color:#FF6600;
}
a.selected,a.selected:hover{
    color:#000000;
}
```

Now, on your function slidedown you can add a class .selected when you click on the link.

```
this.className = this.className + " selected";
```

Comment: I understand the css part I don't understand what goes in my slidedown function.

Comment: Inside your slidedown function you just need to add the javascript line. That's adding the class name "selected" to your link.

Comment: I added it using setattribute, however it is still changing back to white after I hover.

Comment: Make sure you took the onmouseover and onmouseout of your element

Answer (score 1):

You could add a certain styling class to your link when it is clicked which overwrites the other styling and suppresses the mouseover styling.

Comment: I added the code to change the link color on click under slidedown(this), however after I hover again it goes back to white or orange, how could I make this overwrite the hover?

Comment: add !important to the colouring in css

Answer (score 0):

Apply the hover to a class and make a toogle that changes the link class when clicked, this way the hover will not be applied to the clicked link.